# Form isn't sending POST parameters?

Tags: 6, forms, webforms

I want to have a single email field form on my page to suscribe to a newsletter and when the user submit this form, to redirect to a complete form (with name, surname...)

The complete form is designed with Webforms module and this single field form with the Form API in a custom module.

I'm using Drupal 6.25.

The problem is when I submit this form; I feel it don't send any POST parameters. I get them in Webform by setting a default value for the E-mail field at %post[newsletter_mail] and it doesn't work.

This is my code.

```
function block_contact_newsletter_form() {
  $form['description'] = array(
    '#type' => 'item',
    '#title' => t('Suscribe to Newsletter !')
  );

  $form['newsletter_mail'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#default_value' => t('Your E-mail')
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit', 
    '#value' => t('OK'),
  );

  return $form;
}

function theme_block_contact_newsletter_form($form) {
  $output = '';
  $output .= drupal_render($form['description']);
  $output .= drupal_render($form['newsletter_mail']);
  $output .= drupal_render($form['submit']);
  $output .= drupal_render($form);

  return $output;
}

function block_contact_newsletter_form_theme() {
  $themes = array();

  $themes['newsletter_form'] = array(
    'arguments' => array(),
  );

  return $themes;
}

function block_contact_newsletter_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $link_newsletter = drupal_get_path_alias('node/'.variable_get('webform_newsletter_default_nid', ''), $language->language);
  if (strstr($path_newsletter, 'node/') !== FALSE) {
    $link_newsletter = drupal_get_path_alias('node/'.variable_get('webform_newsletter_default_nid', ''), 'fr');
  }

  $form_state['redirect'] = $link_newsletter; 
}

function block_contact_default() {
  $content = array();
  $content[] = '<div class="logo">My.<span>Sitwe</span></div>';

  $items[] = array('class' => 'mail', 'data' => l(t("By mail"), 'node/'.variable_get('webform_contact_default_nid', FALSE)));
  $chat = variable_get('default_chat', "");
  if (!empty($chat)) {
    $items[] = array('class' => 'chat', 'data' => l(t("By chat"), variable_get('default_chat', "")));
  }

  $facebook = variable_get('default_facebook', "");
  if (!empty($facebook)) {
    $items[] = array('class' => 'facebook', 'data' => l("Facebook", $facebook));
  }

  $twitter = variable_get('default_twitter', "");
  if (!empty($twitter)) {
    $items[] = array('class' => 'twitter', 'data' => l("Twitter", 'http://twitter.com/'. $twitter));
  }


// The interesting part for this function begins here.
  $items[] = array('class' => 'newsletter_form', 'data' => drupal_get_form('block_contact_newsletter_form'));

  $content[] = theme('item_list', $items);

  return array(
    'subject' => t("Contacts"),
    'content' => implode('', $content),
    'classes' => array('block-ot-contact')
  );    
}
```

Do you have any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're telling the form to submit via POST, and then once it's done submitting, to redirect to the webform. I think what you intended to do was to make the form submit its data straight to the webform, which you could do with the #action key in the $form array. See http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/6#action

However, this isn't really a very robust approach. A better approach would be to put together your own webform, and then put that webform into a block. If you need to do any custom processing on the webform, the webform module has its own API and hooks that you can use.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I now use $form['#action'] instead of $form_state['redirect'] and I check into Network traffic in Google Chrome and my POST parameter is sent but I can't retrieve it in my Webform. Do you have an idea other than create a new Webform ? Thank you again

Comment: That's a slightly different question! If you can see the POST is working properly, the original question has been answered. You should post a new question with a different title.

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31985/cant-retrieve-post-parameters-in-webform