# Can't retrieve POST parameters in Webform

Tags: forms, webforms

This post is the continuation of this question : [Form isn't sending POST parameters?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31969/form-isnt-sending-post-parameters)

I now have difficulties to retrieve my parameters in a Webform. In Chrome, I can see that my parameter is sent **but the POST header have a "302 Moved Temporarily" status**

In my webform I try to get my parameter with %post[email] but it don't works

Here is my code using the Form API in a custom module (see my old post for more informations)

```
function gn_ot_block_contact_newsletter_form()
{
  $form = array();

  $link_newsletter = drupal_get_path_alias('node/'.variable_get('gn_ot_webform_newsletter_default_nid', ''), $language->language);
  if(strstr($path_newsletter, 'node/') !== FALSE){
    $link_newsletter = drupal_get_path_alias('node/'.variable_get('gn_ot_webform_newsletter_default_nid', ''), 'fr');
  }

  $form['#action'] = base_path() . $link_newsletter;
  $form['description'] = array(
    '#type' => 'item',
    '#title' => t('INSCRIVEZ-VOUS A LA NEWSLETTER !')
  );    
  $form['email'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#default_value' => t('Votre adresse e-mail')
  ); 
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit', 
    '#value' => t('OK'),
  );

  return ($form);
}
```

I'm using Drupal 6.25. Thank you if you have any advice !

Comment: Why you create WebForm programmatically? What is you goal?

Comment: No my Webform isn't create with code. I have my Webform on a page  and a single-field form (in a custom block) on my index page (with email field). My goal is to automatically complete email field on the full newsletter webform with data from my custom single-field form.

Comment: So I don't understand your problem at all. Provide more info, please.

Comment: So email field is visible only in one-field form?

Comment: I have two email fields : One in my one-field form on index page and the second in my full Webform which I want to be automatically filled when submitting the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6) to change value of full form email field. Just take value from table or session where you save one-field email result per user.

Comment: Can I use Webform configuration to change default value ? Because when I put a default value for my Webform field (%post[email]) and I create my form with Full HTML, it works. But when I use the Form API it failed with this "303 Moved Temporarly" warning for the POST header. Really sorry for difficulties I have to explain my problems..

Comment: IMHO it is because after on-field form submission you getting redirect, so that why is 303. You can disable redirection in form settings as I am concerned

Comment: You're my hero ! With your recommendations I add $form['#redirect'] = FALSE; in my code and it works like a charm. Thank you very much :D !

Comment: Glad I can help